# Android: How to center activity label

Tags: android, android-actionbar, label

I want to make the label(My App) to be aligned centrally in action bar. How should I do?

Here is the current screen:

[image: Home screen]

Comment: Are you using Toolbar?

Comment: Did you try my answer @Ji Ya?

Comment: tried. It could let the label come to middle, but not centered. There is gear icon on the right side of bar, so the label is a little bit to the left from the center. Anyway, the solution works. I will try toolbar later. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `Toolbar` you might try this out :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My App"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you are using `ActionBar` try this :

In your `onCreate()` add this :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.your_LAYOUT);
```

And `your_LAYOUT` should be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="myApp"
    android:id="@+id/tvtitle" />
```

Comment: If I only use **Activity**, what should I do?

```<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>```

Comment: Where you are using Activity?