# Android application: How do I center activity label?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, label, android-manifest

I don't create a toolbar in Activity. I simply indicate the activity label in the Manifest file.

Is there a way to center this label?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533510/android-toolbar-center-title-and-custom-font

Comment: This `label` property indicate your activity title. That means if your activity is using either `ActionBar` or `Toolbar` it will automatically show in your activity. So your intention is you want to put this `ActionBar` in the center?

Comment: This'll help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37869535

Comment: You will have to create a custom toolbar